# Is there a way to display text in cocos2d-x in every character set without using a TTF?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Currently I use Label::createWithTTF.

The problem is I want to support all languages (Japanese / Korean / Hindi / Hebrew... etc.)

Is there an alternative to using the Label where I can use a single built-in font to automatically display the text correctly ?

It would be very tedious to add a font for each language.

Answer (score 1):

use  Label::createWithSystemFont
it will support all character also emoticon etc...

sorry didnt see the year of this post